Is Additional Bootstrapping Useful Before Training a Random Forest?
I am reviewing a codebase that uses a Random Forest (RF) Regressor, and I've noticed that bootstrapping is applied before creating each RF model. However, RF inherently uses bootstrapping to train each Decision Tree (DT).
Does it make sense and is it usefull to use additional bootstrapping before creating a Random Forest?
Here's an illustration of the process:

From 75 training observations, 100 bootstrap batches are created.
Each bootstrap batch is used to train an RF, which itself consists
of 100 DTs.
In total, we will train 1000 DTs.
At the end, the predictions from each DT are aggregated to form the
RF prediction.
Finally, the predictions from all RFs are aggregated to obtain the final result.



Sry, not getting your point. Could you please give reference to an article that is saying same as you described? Generally RF estimate = mean(DT1+DT2+...). For each DT you boostrap the data and then additionally you bootstrap features. But you are saying that RF_estimate is a sum of other RF_estimates which doesn't make sense for me.

Or your question more about how RF is estimating metrics from train/test splits? In this case the picture is not correct.

Before each DT the RF bootstrap 75% of the data which is used to train DT and the 25% goes to test set which is used to measure performance of trained DT. Then on the second DT the process repeats with a new 75/25 split.

If the bootstrapping of the data before passing to the model is generic (i.e. no stratification or class rebalancing) then yes, it is redundant and could be replaced by setting the number of trees in a single random forest to 1000.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Sorry for the confusion. When I said "predictions from each DT are aggregated", I meant RF_estimate = mean(DT1+DT2+...), and not RF_estimate = DT1+DT2+.... It was a language issue.

@JohnnyCheesecutter I agree that the RF use bootstrapping internaly for each DT to pick max_samples (e.g. 75%). I don't have question on the RF itself. My question is more on the usage of an "additional" bootstrapping, that will be used to create multiple RFs.

Me still wondering where in the code you saw bootstrapping: I am reviewing a codebase that uses a Random Forest (RF) and I've noticed that bootstrapping is applied before creating each RF model. Where exactly in the RF code you saw that there are dozens RFs training? Could you please provide sklearn package version and exact code lines if possible.

@MaximeCharrière Are you referring to a custom implementation of Random Forests or the standard implementation in scikit-learn? In scikit-learn, a Random Forest is composed of multiple decision trees and does not typically involve training multiple separate forests as your illustration suggests. Clarifying this could help us understand your setup better and provide more accurate insights.

@MaximeCharrière "Before each DT the RF bootstrap 75% of the data which is used to train DT and the 25% goes to test set which is used to measure performance of trained DT. Then on the second DT the process repeats with a new 75/25 split." --> Are you referring to cross-validation?
